# Conditional rendering in React. How can I change the logic?

Tags: reactjs

The following component renders a div with the class `title-wrapper` and its `h2` child only if the prop `title` exists.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MyTitle = (props) => {
  const { title, link } = props;

  return (
    title
      ? (
        <div className="title-wrapper">
          <h2 data-text={title}>
            {link ? (<a href={link} title={title}>{title}</a>) : (<span>{title}</span>)}
          </h2>
        </div>
      )
      : null
  );
};

MyTitle.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  link: PropTypes.string,
};

MyTitle.defaultProps = {
  link: '',
};

export default MyTitle;
```

I'd like to change the above logic so that it always renders the `title-wrapper` div even if the props `title` doesn't exist but renders the `h2` only if the props `title` exist.

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Move the div outside the conditional expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always display the wrapper, then use && to conditionally render the title inside of it.

```
const MyTitle = (props) => {
  const { title, link } = props;
  
  return (
    <div className="title-wrapper">
      { title && 
          <h2 data-text={title}>
            {link ? (<a href={link} title={title}>{title}</a>) : (<span>{title}</span>)}
          </h2>
      }
    </div>
  )
};
```